# Handling multiple listeners with a kind of identification

Tags: java, android, interface, callback, listener

I develop a Android application for a Ble-Device and implement a *Interface* to listen on write, read and subscribe operations. I add all my listener instances to a *List* and trigger the *Interface* methods like this:

```
readWriteEvent = new BleDevice.ReadWriteEvent(true, status, characteristic.getValue());
                for (ReadWriteListener listener : readWriteListener) {
                    listener.onEvent(readWriteEvent);
                }
```

But the problem is, that all *ReadWriteEvents* get triggered who have an active listener. So is there some kind of identification where I can trigger a specific listener ? So that I can do something like this:

```
for (ReadWriteListener listener : readWriteListener) {
 if (listener.getUuid() == characteristic.getUuid()) { 
  listener.onEvent(readWriteEvent);
 }
}
```

Or is there a better solution for my problem ? This is how my *Interface* looks know:

```
public interface ReadWriteListener {
void onEvent(BleDevice.ReadWriteEvent event);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an abstract class instead:

```
public abstract class ReadWriteListener {
    private int uid;

    public ReadWriteListener(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public int getUid() {
        return uid; //or just make uid final and public
    }

    public abstract void onEvent(BleDevice.ReadWriteEvent event);
}
```

This way, when you construct it, you can pass a UID and retrieve it, while the `onEvent` method remains abstract and necessary to implement. Of course, this means you can no longer implement the listener in a class that's already extending another class.